# Getting data from a Linq DbContext to a stored procedure

Tags: linq

I am calling a stored procedure using Linq. I want to put that data in list. Can anyone help me how to do this? You can see my code here:

```
public getidrange(int startrange, int endrange)
{
   List<string> idRange = new List<string>();
   string Conn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydbconnection"].ToString();

   GetIDRangeDataContext GetIdRange = new GetIDRangeDataContext(Conn);

   try
   {
       GetIdRange.sp_GetIdRange(startRange, endRange);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {

   }

   return idRange;
}
```

Comment: what your stored procedure returns?

Comment: it returns id range example 1002 to 1008 all id between this range.

Comment: if your stored procedure is returning the id range then, store it in some variable, idRange = GetIdRange.sp_GetIdRange(startRange, endRane).ToList(); are you getting any error with that..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did the following to and it worked .

```
 try
        {
          var res =  GetIdRange.sp_GetIdRange(startRange, endRange);
          foreach (var ids in res)
          {
              idRange.Add(ids.NewIDAnalisi.ToString());
              objGetIdRangeResults.success = true;
          }
```